# AdColony ad restarting app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, adcolony

I am currently making an iOS game using sprite kit. In one of my SKScenes, my store scene, the user can watch an AdColony ad. The ad plays fine, but after it is finished, the store scene is deallocated and the app returns to the menu screen. Why is this happening, and how can I return to the store scene without deallocating it?

Edit: Here's my code

```
//User taps a button (really a skspritenode)

//UIAlertView pops up asking them to watch a video

alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    //User tapped button 1 (aka agreed to watch video)
    if (buttonIndex == 1){

        //Present video
        [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" withDelegate:self];
        }];


}
```

Comment: No code, no attempts, no luck.

Comment: @sangony I just added the code above. But that's what confuses me the most: all I'm doing is calling the playVideoAd method

Comment: I would try a scene without any additional code aside from your adColony. If you're still having issues, I recommend you contact them for support.

Comment: Just made a stripped down project where the store scene is simply an skscene with a white background that plays a video after 1.5 seconds. The problems still persists. I'll contact AdColony.